# how to hide value axes label am5charts?

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts

Using LineGraph example from amCharts demo area, I want to hide the Y axis labels. I have tried many things from older version but have not got any success.

here is the original demo link: https://www.amcharts.com/demos/line-graph/ and Code:

```js
/**
 * ---------------------------------------
 * This demo was created using amCharts 5.
 * 
 * For more information visit:
 * https://www.amcharts.com/
 * 
 * Documentation is available at:
 * https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/
 * ---------------------------------------
 */

// Create root element
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/getting-started/#Root_element
var root = am5.Root.new("chartdiv");


// Set themes
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/concepts/themes/
root.setThemes([
  am5themes_Animated.new(root)
]);


// Create chart
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/
var chart = root.container.children.push(am5xy.XYChart.new(root, {
  panX: true,
  panY: true,
  wheelX: "panX",
  wheelY: "zoomX",
  pinchZoomX:true
}));


// Add cursor
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/cursor/
var cursor = chart.set("cursor", am5xy.XYCursor.new(root, {
  behavior: "none"
}));
cursor.lineY.set("visible", false);


// Generate random data
var date = new Date();
date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
var value = 100;

function generateData() {
  value = Math.round((Math.random() * 10 - 5) + value);
  am5.time.add(date, "day", 1);
  return {
    date: date.getTime(),
    value: value
  };
}

function generateDatas(count) {
  var data = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    data.push(generateData());
  }
  return data;
}


// Create axes
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/axes/
var xAxis = chart.xAxes.push(am5xy.DateAxis.new(root, {
  maxDeviation: 0.2,
  baseInterval: {
    timeUnit: "day",
    count: 1
  },
  renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererX.new(root, {}),
  tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(root, {})
}));

var yAxis = chart.yAxes.push(am5xy.ValueAxis.new(root, {
  renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererY.new(root, {})
}));


// Add series
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/series/
var series = chart.series.push(am5xy.LineSeries.new(root, {
  name: "Series",
  xAxis: xAxis,
  yAxis: yAxis,
  valueYField: "value",
  valueXField: "date",
  tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(root, {
    labelText: "{valueY}"
  })
}));


// Add scrollbar
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/scrollbars/
chart.set("scrollbarX", am5.Scrollbar.new(root, {
  orientation: "horizontal"
}));


// Set data
var data = generateDatas(1200);
series.data.setAll(data);


// Make stuff animate on load
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/concepts/animations/
series.appear(1000);
chart.appear(1000, 100);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
max-width: 100%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/index.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/xy.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/themes/Animated.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

I have tried soultions:

```
axis.disabled = true;
```

and

```
valueAxis.renderer.labels.template.adapter.add("text", function(text, target) {
  return text.match(/\./) ? "" : text;
});
```

and

```
let yAxis = chart.yAxes.push(am5xy.ValueAxis.new(root, {
        disabled: true,
        renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererY.new(root, {}),
      }));
```

any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gotcha, Simply I found pass the setting value visible property while creating the axis.

```
var yAxis = chart.yAxes.push(am5xy.ValueAxis.new(root, {
  visible: false,
  renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererY.new(root, {})
}));
```

Works prefect!.